# Would a crystal that generates second harmonic would generate third harmonic as well?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, group-theory, non-linear-optics

Isotropic media usually can generate odd harmonics $X^{(2n)}=0$.

What about non-isotropic. Would a crystal that generates SH would generate third ? Is there crystals group that generates all harmonics ?

My question is just about the symmetries and the non zero nonlinear susceptibilities $X^{(2n)}$, and $X^{(2n+1)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be a little careful with your terminology.  The property that determines whether or not SHG occurs is *centrosymmetry*.   *Isotropy*  is a stronger condition that need not be met for SHG to occur.

All materials exhibit the odd harmonics.  The even harmonics occur only in materials that are not centrosymmetric.

Comment: Thanks. Do all those materials that have $X^{2n}$ also have $X^{2n+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes.  *All* materials have a non-zero $\chi^{2n+1}$.  Even gases.